# Intellij idea проблема с run configuration (applyEditorTo)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains

Пишу плагин для intellij idea. Создаю ран конфигурацию (класс наследуют от SettingsEditor), переопределяю метод applyEditorTo. Проблема вот в чем: при дебаге выясняется, что при открытии ран конфигурации (Run->Edit Configuration) выполняется этот метод. Но ведь он должен выполняться при нажатии Apply.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу на собственный вопрос.
Метод: 
`void applyEditorTo(? extends DeploymentConfiguration s) {}`

выполняется в бесконечном цикле  и "применяется" не к основной конфигурации, а к временной. И потом сравнивая временную с основной просчитывается, надо ли кнопку "Apply" делать активной.